# Passing an Object to the constructor of another class and calling methods on that Object

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple application which calculates a value by multiplying a user input int against the current int state of a `seekBar` UI view in an Android Application. However, even though I am manipulating the `seekBar` in the UI and the value of its `progress` is changing, the `getSeekProgress()`, doesn't seem to return a value beyond 0.

```
public class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener {

MainActivity caller;
SeekBarListener seekBarListener;

ButtonListener(MainActivity activity, SeekBarListener seekListener) {
    this.caller = activity;
    seekBarListener = seekListener;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    int seekProgress = seekBarListener.getSeekProgress();
    int principal = Integer.parseInt(caller.principal.getText().toString());
    int interest = Integer.parseInt(caller.interest.getText().toString());
    int finalValue = principal * seekProgress;
    caller.output.setText(Integer.toString(finalValue));
   }

}
```

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: Hi, It seems that my attempt to pass the seekBar Object to the clickListener and for the clickListener to access to the 'SeekProgress' variable state via the 'getSeekProgress' method doesnt work. The method simply returns 0. How do I know why the above logic doesnt work?